# How can I communicate across worker nodes in a service-oriented MS HPC cluster?

Tags: .net, mpi, cluster-computing, soa, hpc

I'm working with an application that uses Microsoft HPC Pack to distribute a calculation across a cluster. The cluster-side implementation uses a Service-Oriented-Architecture, so that clients interact with a service on the cluster's head node which distributes the work across several worker nodes.

I'd now like to pass intermediate results between worker nodes using MPI or a similar technology, what is the best practice for doing so in a service-oriented framework? Is it possible to link several services spawned by a service job in HPC Pack?